# Android gltf-Viewer with Morph-targets and animations

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, 3d, gltf

How would I implement a gltf-3D Object with morph-target-data into my app in Android studio? The user must be able to change the morph-values with a slider while a few sceleton-animations are playing. Gltf is not that common on Android, should I use fbx instead? How would I implement that, and would it run effectively or would it lag or need a lot of battery?

So one Question: Which Library/Code do I need, to implement gltf-Objects? If the answer is, that it is hard to implement, which format should I use instead?